# Android wearables: How to handle the event of a connected device?

Tags: android, event-handling, connection, wear-os, android-wear-data-api

From the smartwatch I'd like to intercept the event of the connection to a smartphone. This is automatically managed by Android and Android Wear so I need to get this event from my app running on the watch.

I found out this on WearableAPI to be notified without polling Wearable.NodeApi.getConnectedNodes

```
public class MyService extends WearableListenerService {
  @Override
  public void onPeerConnected(Node peer) {
    Log.i("my wear service", "connected");
    super.onPeerConnected(peer);
    // here I would use MessageAPI to send data saved on "disk" to the smartphone
  }
}
```

Is it the right way? So is this a normal Service? Do I have to start it or is it automatically running in background?
Are there any other ways to perform this task?

this is the [reference](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/WearableListenerService)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to exchange data between the wearable and the handheld app I strongly suggest you to use the `Wearable.DataApi` or the `Wearable.MessageApi`. You will probably want to to have a subclass of `WearableListenerService` running on both side, and handling the communication `onDataChanged`/`onMessageReceived`. They have an empty implementation on the super class. So you have to override the one you need. If you use the `DataApi` you'll have to override `onDataChanged`, `onMessageReceived` otherwise.

> Do I have to start it or is it automatically running in background

you have to declare your subclass in the manifest, and use `BIND_LISTENER` as action,

```
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.BIND_LISTENER"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Android takes care of the rest.

Comment: Do I have to create a GoogleAPI client inside my Service to make a Wearable.DataApi.putDataItem(mGoogleApiClient, putDataReq)? Is it acceptable?

Comment: it is acceptable. I can't see any reason why it shouldn't be